# How Do I Figure Out What File(s) to Edit from Looking at the Source Code

Tags: plugins, css, html

I just started working at a company and they have a website that was partially completed by another designer and have hired me to complete and make changes to it. It seems that most of the website was created in WordPress, but some of it seems to be done by hand-coding in HTML & CSS.

The website is at http://www.executivetravellink.com/

I do have access to their FTP, so I can transfer the files locally and are able to see them, but my issue is that I can't tell in what files changes were made.
For example, if you see the navigator bar at the top with the "Flights," "Cruises," etc, you can see that the previous designer added small icons next to the links. I know that if you go into Appearance--->Menus that you can add/edit the links on the menu and the images can be inserted from using the style.css file in Wordpress. However, I am not sure in what file he was storing those actual images, so I can add new ones.

Also, I'm having this issue on many pages, but for example on http://www.executivetravellink.com/brands/hotel-brands/, when you go to the hotel-brands page in Wordpress, I can see the first paragraph about Club Med, but I'm assuming the remaining paragraphs are not there and must be in a separate file linked to it. I tried to insert a banner above the first paragraph and it would not show up.

From looking at the source code, would someone be able to know the answer to that?  I’m still very new to Wordpress and can’t say I’m an expert at HTML & CSS either at this point.  Any information that someone could give me would be certainly much appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: Maybe, if you don't know all this, you shouldn't be hired to do this job in the first place? :) All kidding aside: download the whole thing, start browsing and look up every function you don't know. WordPress is not hard to learn it just takes a bit of time.

Comment: This question is too localized, overly broad, and, with respect to HTML/CSS, off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Studying the code is an obvious approach.

You can also try plugins, such as [Debug Bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/) that can easily display you information, such as template being used and so what you are looking at.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the brands might be sub pages. If you go to Pages and look at the Brands page you will probably see that there are pages indented underneath. That would give them the permalink /brands/hotel-brands/club-med  I'm assuming you'll see something like this:

```
Brands
-Hotel Brands
--Club Med
--Couples Resorts
--Crowne Plaze
-Airline Brands
-Car Rental Brands
```

If it's running on Wordpress, there shouldn't be any hand-coding going on other than in the template files. If the previous scenario is correct, they've just added an excerpt in the parent page and then linked to a sub-page. The template that's being rendered is http://www.executivetravellink.com/wp-content/themes/executivetravel.v.1.0/page.php

You should learn about the Wordpress template structure here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_File_Checklist This gives a description of each template file.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the page with firebug ,and you will see for example the css is saved in the theme `executivetravel.v.1.0` , file `style.css` (also you will see the path of the icons there).

You can also download this theme and check the template files (they should be located on 
`/wp-content/themes/executivetravel.v.1.0/` and look at those files to see if maybe he harcoded excerpts there.